# Tomcat isn't working when i run index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I quit at last,

When I try to run my `index.jsp` , I get to debugger

and this exception is printed on the screen:

`jdbcOdbcDriver.finalize() line: not available[local variables are not available]`

I'm using tomcat server

I have no idea why this is happening and google isn't of much help.

Any help would be appreciated.

eli

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, this could be due to a corrupt `.metadata` folder. Try quitting Eclipse, backing up the folder and then deleting it.

More information [here](http://coderzen.blogspot.com/2012/02/jdbcodbcdriverfinalize-line-not.html).

Out of curiosity, why are you using this particular driver and not a [Type 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type%5F4%5FDriver%5F-%5FNative-Protocol%5FDriver) driver?

As an aside, for future JDBC debugging, you might find [p6spy useful](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/).